# WPF Dynamic tree view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

i am stuck with WPF tree view i have a model.

```
public class FullCompany
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfFoundation { get; set; }
    public string LegalAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
}
public class Posts
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Director { get; set; }
   public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
   public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I receive if from database, but i can't understand how to make it to hiearchical tree view
i tried like this, it must hide by button. I searched for example but they doesn't work , in my case.

[company -> department -> employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/290iL.png)

my xaml code

```
<TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding FullCompanies}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"  x:Name="SubTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"  x:Name="SubTreeView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                                        <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                            </TreeView>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        </TreeView>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                       
                        
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I don't believe that any example with HierarchicalDataTemplate had TreeView inside that HierarchicalDataTemplate. HierarchicalDataTemplate should use its ItemsSource property

Comment: In the resources of your treeview define hierarchicaldatatemplates associated with datatype. No itemtemplate. Each should have an itemssource bound to the children property in the type.

Comment: See the multiple templates second example here https://wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for advices , i finally made it. From @BionicCode example:

```
<DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <viewmodels:MainViewModel x:Key="FullCompanies"/>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type models:FullCompany}"
                            ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Posts}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type models:Posts}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Employees}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type models:Employee}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </DockPanel.Resources>

        <Menu Name="menu1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <MenuItem Header="Companies"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FullCompanies}" />
        </Menu>

        <TreeView>
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding FullCompanies}" Header="Companies" />
        </TreeView>

    </DockPanel>
```